# Processing binary data in Rust

Tags: performance, rust

I have binary files that need to be efficiently processed. The first 8 bytes correspond to metadata, and all the rest is data. From the first 8 bytes I need the last 4 bytes to determine how to structure the rest of the data.

Since I'm new to rust, this seemed like a good exercise. The following code complies and produces results that seeem reasonable.

```
use std::convert::TryInto;
use ndarray::Array2;
use chrono::prelude::*;


fn four_bytes_to_array(barry: &[u8]) -> &[u8; 4] {
    barry.try_into().expect("slice with incorrect length")
}

fn eight_bytes_to_array(barry: &[u8]) -> &[u8; 8] {
    barry.try_into().expect("slice with incorrect length")
}


fn bin_file_to_matrix(file_name: &str) -> ndarray::Array2<f64> {
    // Read in file_content
    let mut file_content = std::fs::read(file_name).expect("Could not read file!");
    
    // The first 4 bytes are some random information, the second 4 bytes are the
    // number of data-points per spectrum
    let nr_dp_per_spectrum = four_bytes_to_array(&file_content[4..8]);

    // We combine the 4 bytes into an unsigned integer
    let nr_dp_per_spectrum = u32::from_be_bytes(*nr_dp_per_spectrum);
    
    // Calculate how many spectra there are in this file
    let how_many_spectra = file_content.len() as u32/8/(nr_dp_per_spectrum + 1u32);

    // Create a buffer to write the data to
    let dim = ndarray::Dim([how_many_spectra as usize, nr_dp_per_spectrum as usize]);
    let mut data = Array2::<f64>::zeros(dim);

    // Remove the first 8 bytes that contain metadata we have already processed
    file_content.drain(0..8);

    for i in 0..how_many_spectra {
        for j in 0..nr_dp_per_spectrum {

            let idx = ( (nr_dp_per_spectrum+1) * i + j * 8 ) as usize;
            let tmp = eight_bytes_to_array( &file_content[idx..idx+8] );
            let val = f64::from_be_bytes( *tmp );

            data[ndarray::Ix2(i as usize, j as usize)] = val;
        }
    }

    data
}


fn main() {
    let start = Utc::now();
    let res = bin_file_to_matrix("./data/example.bin");
    let difference = Utc::now() - start;

    println!("Time:\t {:?}", difference);
}
```

Is there a way to speed up the code?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to speed up the code?

The speed is determined only be the nested for loop. Nothing glaring stands out to me. **Are you compiling in debug mode (without most optimizations) or in release mode (with optimizations on)?**

I cleaned up your code somewhat, though I don't expect it to have any performance impact, mostly reducing necessity of casts and adding a generic wrapper around `from_be_bytes` which automatically advances the reference to the bytes to be read by the correct amount. This also obviates the need for calculating the index in the loop, which may have a slight performance impact, though similar work is instead done by `read_be`, so the impact is probably small...

```
use chrono::prelude::*;
use ndarray::Array2;
use std::convert::TryInto;

trait EndianRead {
    fn read_be(input: &mut &[u8]) -> Self;
}

macro_rules! impl_EndianRead_for_nums (( $($num:ident),* ) => {
    $(
        impl EndianRead for $num {
            fn read_be(input: &mut &[u8]) -> Self {
                let (bytes, rest) = input.split_at(std::mem::size_of::<Self>());
                *input = rest;
                Self::from_be_bytes(bytes.try_into().unwrap())
            }
        }
    )*
});

impl_EndianRead_for_nums!(u32, f64);

fn bin_file_to_matrix(file_name: &str) -> ndarray::Array2<f64> {
    // Read in file_content
    let file_content = std::fs::read(file_name).expect("Could not read file!");

    // The first 4 bytes are some random information
    let mut byte_content = &file_content[4..];
    
    // the second 4 bytes are the number of data-points per spectrum
    // We combine the 4 bytes into an unsigned integer
    let nr_dp_per_spectrum = <u32 as EndianRead>::read_be(&mut byte_content) as usize;

    // Calculate how many spectra there are in this file
    let spectrum_size = std::mem::size_of::<f64>() * nr_dp_per_spectrum;
    let how_many_spectra = byte_content.len() / spectrum_size;

    // Create a buffer to write the data to
    let dim = ndarray::Dim([how_many_spectra, nr_dp_per_spectrum]);
    let mut data = Array2::<f64>::zeros(dim);

    for i in 0..how_many_spectra {
        for j in 0..nr_dp_per_spectrum {
            let val = <f64 as EndianRead>::read_be(&mut byte_content);
            data[ndarray::Ix2(i as usize, j as usize)] = val;
        }
    }

    data
}

fn main() {
    let start = Utc::now();
    let _res = bin_file_to_matrix("./data/example.bin");
    let difference = Utc::now() - start;

    println!("Time:\t {:?}", difference);
}
```

Comment: `I cleaned up your code ...` I suspect there are more observations you could make about the code. Could you answer in the question what about the code made you clean it up.

Comment: @pacmaninbw, thanks for your suggestion. It was mostly my impression of too much casting going on, so I'll add that in my answer.